# Android change camera preview size and position on SurfaceView

Tags: android

I want to make an application that shows a camera preview on a surface view. the SurfaceView fills the screen, but I want to show the preview only on a certain position of the screen, in a smaller square. I want to draw other things later on the surfaceview too, around the preview. My problem is that the preview fills the whole surfaceview. Is there a way to resolve this problem? I read that I can't use more than one SurfaceView at the same time to separate the preview and the drawing.

Thank you for your help!